# Why doesn't the background color cover the whole button tag when written in .btn::before?

Tags: html, css, button

I've trying to understand the hover effect in CSS. Have created 4 buttons and filled blue color #3498db as the background color. Unfortunately, I don't understand why using `content:""` and `left:0px` fills the button box half.

[image: button boxes half filled with background colour]

Html code -

```
<body>
    <div class="buttonbox">
      <button class="btn btn1">Hover me!</button>
      <button class="btn btn2">Hover me!</button>
      <button class="btn btn3">Hover me!</button>
      <button class="btn btn4">Hover me!</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS code -

```
.btn{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100px;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left:0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3498db;
}

.btn1, .btn2{
  color: #3498db;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.btn3, .btn4{
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.btn1:hover, .btn2:hover{
  color: #fff;
}

.btn3:hover, .btn4:hover{
  color: #3498db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `top: 0;` to `.btn::before`. If either X and Y position for an absolutely positioned element is missing, it is placed where it would be normally, it is **not** set to 0 (this can be useful sometimes, although it is not very usual to use absolute positioning without setting both X and Y positions).
`content: ""` is necessary for before and after pseudo-elements - otherwise, it wouldn't exist (try removing the property in your browser developer tools, it will disappear).

Answer (score 0):

[check the css content property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp)  for this situation.

The confusion about your css code is that: I think you need to set bg color of .btn class not btn::before. Because ::before adds a new item an sets its bg color.
And if you set a string in content attribute it will add that string to before the related item.

Check my following code. I removed buttons inner texts and set them via ::before content attribute.

```css
.btn{
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #3498db;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn::before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "Hover me!";
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:12px;
}

.btn1, .btn2{
  color: #3498db;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.btn3, .btn4{
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.btn1:hover, .btn2:hover{
  color: #fff;
}

.btn3:hover, .btn4:hover{
  color: #3498db;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="buttonbox">
      <button class="btn btn1"></button>
      <button class="btn btn2"></button>
      <button class="btn btn3"></button>
      <button class="btn btn4"></button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use just

background-size: cover

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply. I just wanted to know that why does it not cover fully? and what is the use of content:"" here?

Comment: Hello, here he is asking the reason, not the solution.